# Do Duplo trains fit Megablock train tracks?

Tags: clone-brands, trains, duplo, tracks

Do Duplo trains fit Megablock train tracks (given in the picture)?

Note that all the Megablock 2x2, 2x4, etc blocks fit Duplo. I just have never heard about Megablock train tracks' compatibility.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Nooooooo

Size comparison of the trains:
[image: Mega Train]

The Duplo train does **not** fit:
[image: Mega Train]

The Duplo train does **not** fit:
[image: Mega Train]

However: some of you may be thinking of the old Duplo Road pieces, like from set [3267](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=3267-1)
[image: 3267]

The tracks seem similar in width:
[image: Mega Train]

But the Mega Bloks train does not *quite* fit.
[image: Mega Train]

[image: Mega Train]

Based on the slightly greater width of the Mega Bloks track, I would expect the Duplo vehicles from that set to fit on the Mega Bloks track (but perhaps not be able to corner that well).

Comment: A very thorough answer. Thank you very much.